# perform ldapmodify from remote server

Tags: ldap

I am trying to perform an ldapmodify from a remote host to modify entries on my ldapmaster. I already installed slapd on my host because I need mkntpwd binary, the server is not configured, and I also installed ldap-utils for the ldap tools.
When I run the command from the shell it works fine, but not from my script. I am performing the command from the script as follow:

```
.......
echo "dn: ou=xxx,dc=yyy,dc=zzz 
changetype: modify
replace: attribute
attribute: ${newValue}" \
    | ldapmodify -D "${ldapadmindn}" -w "${ldappassword}" -x -H ldaps://myldapmaster:636 >/dev/null 2>&1
.......
```

I tried it also with an ldif file this way:

```
.......
(
    echo "dn: ou=xxx,dc=yyy,dc=zzz"
    echo "changetype: modify"
    echo "replace: attribute"
    echo "attribute: ${newValue}"
) >> file.ldif
ldapmodify -D "${ldapadmindn}" -w "${ldappassword}" -x -H ldaps://myldapmaster:636 -f file.ldif >/dev/null 2>&1
.......
```

unfortunately neither nor worked from my script. as I said both versions works fine from the shell. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Could you remove the redirection to /dev/null, run it again, and post the error message.

Comment: Hi @sborsky, here the error message: `modifying entry "ou=xxx,dc=yyy,dc=zzz changetype: modify replace: attribute attribute: newValue" ldap_modify: Server is unwilling to perform (53)   additional info: no global superior knowledgecode` thanks

Comment: I am wondering that I can perform the query from the shell but not from the script!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve this issue by removing the white spaces at line begin of each line follows the echo command. With the ldif file the problem was that the file wasn't empty, after deleting it, it worked fine. Thanks a lot

Issue can be marked as resolved

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange :). "Issue can be marked as resolved" is up to you: you can accept your own answer by clicking on the tick mark below the upvote/downvote arrows.